# Error: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, get

Tengo el siguiente codigo para extraer unos valores de mi base de datos tras seleccionar un item desde un recyclerview pero me dice que no encontro el metodo para extraer el valor

estoy trabajando con fragments, en la clase HomeFragment tengo un recyclerview con un onClick al seleccionar determinado item me redirije a una vista detalles pero me marca que no encuentra los valores `get`, anexo mis codigos.

HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentHomeBinding binding;

    RecyclerView recyclerUsuarios;
    ArrayList<Usuario> listaUsuarios;
    RampasAdapter adaptador;
    Usuario usuario;

    ProgressDialog progress;

    // RequestQueue request;
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View vista=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        recyclerUsuarios= (RecyclerView) vista.findViewById(R.id.idRecycler);
        recyclerUsuarios.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this.getContext(), 1));

        listaUsuarios=new ArrayList<>();

        cargarWebService();

        adaptador = new RampasAdapter(HomeFragment.this, listaUsuarios);
        recyclerUsuarios.setAdapter(adaptador);

        return vista;
    }

    public void cargarWebService() {

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, getResources().getString(R.string.ip),
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Usuarios");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String nr = jsonObject1.getString("rampa");
                                String name = jsonObject1.getString("trailer");
                                String puesto = jsonObject1.getString("plant_code");
                                String dept = jsonObject1.getString("accion");
                                String ven = jsonObject1.getString("type_material");
                                String img = jsonObject1.getString("prog_date");


                                listaUsuarios.add(new Usuario(nr, name, puesto, dept, ven, img));

                            }

                            adaptador = new RampasAdapter(HomeFragment.this, listaUsuarios);
                            recyclerUsuarios.setAdapter(adaptador);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        );

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

Esta es la clase a donde me redirige el onClick del recyclerview que esta en la clase
HomeFragment

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    FragmentGalleryBinding binding;
    RecyclerView listaFotos;
    FotoAdapter adapter;
    Usuario usuario;

    TextView etTipo,etCaja;

    private List<Bitmap> fotos =  new ArrayList<>();

    public GalleryFragment() {
    }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentGalleryBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        usuario = (Usuario) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("usuario");

        listaFotos=binding.listaFotos;
        adapter=new FotoAdapter(fotos, getContext());
        listaFotos.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 4));
        listaFotos.setAdapter(adapter);

        FloatingActionButton btn=binding.fotografiar;
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                hacerFoto();
            }
        });


        etTipo = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.tvtipo);
        etCaja = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.tvtrailer);

        etTipo.setText(usuario.getDestino());
        etCaja.setText(usuario.getCaja());

        return root;
    }

    private File archivo;
    private void hacerFoto() {
        try {
            Intent i =  new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            archivo = crearFichero();
            Uri foto = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.example.rampasimage.fileprovider", archivo);
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, foto);

            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
        }catch (IOException e){
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error:" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (requestCode==1){
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(archivo.getAbsolutePath());
                fotos.add(image);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }else {

        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private File crearFichero() throws IOException {
        String pre="foto_";
        File directorio=getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File img = File.createTempFile(pre + UUID.randomUUID().toString(),".jpg", directorio);
        return img;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

El metodo que dice que no encuentra es en la siguiente seccion del codigo y por ende los demas no los detectara

`etTipo.setText(usuario.getDestino());`

`etCaja.setText(usuario.getCaja());`

Mi clase Usuario.java es donde extraigo el metodo

```
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    String rampa;
    String caja;
    String destino;
    String accion;
    String tipo;
    String salida;


    public Usuario(String rampa, String caja, String destino, String accion, String tipo, String salida) {
        this.rampa = rampa;
        this.caja = caja;
        this.destino = destino;
        this.accion = accion;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.salida = salida;

    }

    public String getRampa() {
        return rampa;
    }

    public void setRampa(String rampa) {
        this.rampa = rampa;
    }

    public String getCaja() {
        return caja;
    }

    public void setCaja(String caja) {
        this.caja = caja;
    }

    public String getDestino() {
        return destino;
    }

    public void setDestino(String destino) {
        this.destino = destino;
    }

    public String getAccion() {
        return accion;
    }

    public void setAccion(String accion) {
        this.accion = accion;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public String getSalida() {
        return salida;
    }

    public void setSalida(String salida) {
        this.salida = salida;
    }
}
```

Vista del recyclerview junto con su xml de item

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/idRecycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

embarques_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cvTarjeta"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="69dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="69dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Ubicación"
                    android:textSize="13dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlCompat" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtRampa"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:hint="RAMPA"
                    card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    tools:ignore="RtlCompat,RtlHardcoded" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Destino"
                    android:textSize="13dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.257"
                    card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlCompat" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtTipo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:hint="DESTINO"
                    card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.267"
                    card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlCompat" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="69dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Numero de Caja"
                android:textSize="13dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlCompat" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtCaja"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:hint="CAJA"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlCompat,RtlHardcoded,SmallSp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Fecha de Envío"
                android:textSize="13dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.397"
                card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtSalida"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:hint="SALIDA"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.342"
                card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Estatus"
                android:textSize="13dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.676"
                card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtEstatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:hint="ESTATUS"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.689"
                card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlCompat" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDetalles"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@color/read"
                android:text="Agregar Imagenes" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Vista detalles que es donde me falla la aplicacion

fragment_gallery.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/lista_fotos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/style_borde_edittext"
        card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fotografiar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck,MissingClass" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Numero de caja"
        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvtrailer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvtipo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Enviar"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lista_fotos" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en tu layout `fragment_home.xml` no existen los `TextView` con id `tvtipo` y `tvtrailer`,  cuando obtienes la referencia, no encuentra la vista:

```
 etTipo = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.tvtipo);
 etCaja = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.tvtrailer);
```

entonces cuando usas los mètodos `setText()` en las vistas obtendràs `NullPointerException`.

```
 etTipo.setText(usuario.getDestino());
 etCaja.setText(usuario.getCaja());
```

Agrega las vistas a `fragment_home.xml`

Comment: En el fragment home si tengo esas vistas creadas no con el mismo nombre pero si estan y cuando habro el 2do fragment falla, me podrias explicar por que tendria que agregar de nuevo las vistas ya agregue mis xml

Comment: pregunto por que las referencias no las llamo en la clase home_fragment, las referencias las estoy llamando de la clase gallery fragment que es la vista detalles a las cual nos envia el recyclerview que esta en la clase home_fragment

Comment: Al escribir tu código puedes obtener que las vistas existen, pero para obtener las referencias correctamente debes obtenerlas del layout que se carga dentro de onCreateView() en un Fragment o onCreate() en una Activity, así es como funciona android.